# Visual Studio C++ connect to DB2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, db2

I'm trying to write a C ++ program using a database - IBM DB2 Express-C. Also, I use Visual Studio 2015. Via IBM OLE DB Provider for DB2 my Visual Studio successfully connected to DB2. I can see tables and all OK:

[image]

Then I created new C++ program, I successfully connect several header files, some from them I found in my DB2 directory, for example **sqlcli1.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sqlcli1.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

The following is the code of the main program. In which I am trying to connect to the database to which successfully was connected the Visual Studio.

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int main()
{
    SQLHENV henv;
    SQLHDBC hdbc;
    SQLHSTMT hstmt;
    SQLRETURN retcode;

    SQLCHAR * OutConnStr = (SQLCHAR *)malloc(255);
    SQLSMALLINT * OutConnStrLen = (SQLSMALLINT *)malloc(255);

    // Allocate environment handle  
    retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);

    // Set the ODBC version environment attribute  
    if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {


        // Allocate connection handle  
        if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
            retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);




                // Connect to data source  
            retcode = SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLWCHAR*) "DATABASE=SAMPLE;HOSTNAME=localhost", SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*) "db2admin", SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*) "password", SQL_NTS);
                if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) {
                    printf(">--- Error while connecting to database:");
                    printf("SQLConnect: %d\n", retcode);
                }
                // Allocate statement handle  
                if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
                    retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt);
                    printf("\nAllocate Connection handle successfully.");
                    // Process data  
                    if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
                        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
                    }

                    SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
                }

                SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);

        }
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

There are no errors at compile time, but can not connect to the database.When program execution comes to the block.

```
// Connect to data source  
            retcode = SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLWCHAR*) "DATABASE=SAMPLE;HOSTNAME=localhost", SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*) "db2admin", SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*) "password", SQL_NTS);
                if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) {
                    printf(">--- Error while connecting to database:");
                    printf("SQLConnect: %d\n", retcode);
                }
```

I see **>--- Error while connecting to database:SQLConnect:-2**
What does it means? what I am doing is wrong? I also tried it:

```
retcode = SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLWCHAR*) "SAMPLE", SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*) "db2admin", SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*) "password", SQL_NTS);
```

But it also does not work. May be the second argument should look like in some other way?

> Changed
>   I tried use this function **SQLGetDiagRec** I created some variables

```
SQLWCHAR       SqlState[6], SQLStmt[100], Msg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    SQLINTEGER    NativeError;
    SQLSMALLINT   i, MsgLen;
    SQLRETURN     rc1, rc2;
```

I also change my connect block

```
// Connect to data source  
            retcode = SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLWCHAR*) "SAMPLE", SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*) "db2admin", SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*) "password", SQL_NTS);
                if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) {
                    printf(">--- Error while connecting to database:");
                    printf("SQLConnect: %d\n", retcode);

                    if ((retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) || (retcode == SQL_ERROR)) {
                        // Get the status records.  
                        i = 1;
                        while ((rc2 = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, i, SqlState, &NativeError,
                            Msg, sizeof(Msg), &MsgLen)) != SQL_NO_DATA) {
                            cout << SqlState;
                            cout << i;
                            cout << NativeError;
                            cout << Msg;

                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But nothing has changed. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If a call to any CLI function doesn't return `SQL_SUCCESS`, then your error handling should use `SQLGetDiagRec()` to get the details of the warning or error.

Documentation: [SQLGetDiagRec](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0000609.html)

Comment: I tried it **Changed the question**, but the function `SQLGetDiagRec()` does not print anything.